# How to add Chart framework in today extension

Tags: swift

I have chart in my app, I am using framework Charts for creating it. In my today extension, I need to show dashboard with charts, but I don't understand how to import `Charts.framework` to today extension.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'today extension'. If you're using ios-charts then there are tutorials, and the homepage on [github](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Podfile you need to add a target to your Today Extension like below

```
 target 'YourTodayExtension' do
   # Pods for Today Extension
   pod 'Charts'     
  end
```

So you can use your Charts library inside your Today Extension.